# C-22 Ubuntu 14.10 64bit: "booting in insecure mode" message

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit

Booting Ubuntu 14.10 64Bit brings the message "Booting in insecure mode".

How to repaire it? What does it mean? What are the consequences?

Who knows?

Daniel

Answer (score 2):

You are using a UEFI boot, in BIOS, but have told the BIOS to not boot in a secure mode.  There were problems earlier with UEFI and Ubuntu, but I am using secure boot with Ubuntu 14.10 and not having issues at this time.

[Secure boot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Secure_boot) prevents drivers from loading unless they have an acceptable digital signature.  You can try eneabling secure boot in your BIOS with 14.04, and if it does not work, just turn the secure boot back off.

Answer (score 1):

From Ubuntu 14.10 release notes page:

> An update to shim in 14.10 introduces a bug where, when booting on a UEFI system with SecureBoot disabled, the boot is delayed for two seconds and a message "Booting in insecure mode" is displayed on the screen. This message does not indicate a security problem with Ubuntu and does not interfere with the operation of the system except for introducing this boot delay. As a workaround to avoid this boot delay, users can enable SecureBoot if enabled on their hardware, or if they do not intend to use SecureBoot at all they can uninstall the shim-signed package and then rerun the grub-install command. [1384973](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1384973)